# How to get ipv6 to work?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

My provider uses DSLite for internet connections, which means that I do not have a unique ip4. However, if I loook into my cable modem, it shows an ip6 address. To get all of this to run, I wanted to start with having ip6 functionality within my own network, without any internet stuff.
So, I have two linux machines which are connected to a router, Netgear WNDR3700v3, which runs a DDWRT custom rom.
Using ifconfig on both machines reveals ip6 addresses, for example
fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773/64

But, when I want to try a simple ping, using

```
ping6 9d5a:f005:2c85:9773::fe80
```

I only get

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Soooo, how can I get at least a simple ping running using ip6?

Thx.

Comment: The `fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773` is a valid, link-local, IPv6 address, but the `9d5a:f005:2c85:9773::fe80` address you are trying to ping is an invalid, IPv6 address.

Comment: but if I type `ping6 fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773` it says `connect: Invalid argument`

Comment: That is because you are not including the scope. Every interface in a host uses the same link-local network, so you must include the scope when using link-local addresses. Since you didn't include the scope, the scope argument is invalid, and the error message is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773` is a valid, link-local, IPv6 address, but the `9d5a:f005:2c85:9773::fe80` address you are trying to ping is an invalid, IPv6 address.

> but if I type `ping6 fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773` it says `connect: Invalid argument`

That is because you are not including the scope. Every interface in a host uses the same link-local network, so you must include the scope when using link-local addresses. Since you didn't include the scope, the scope argument is invalid, and the error message is correct. What the scope ID is depends on the host OS and the interface which you want to use.

For example:

```
ping6 fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773%2
```

or

```
ping6 fe80::9d5a:f005:2c85:9773%eth0
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I found that it also works if I specify which network adapter to use, by typing ping6 -I eth0 ... Now I wanted to ping google. I found the google ip6 dns server,  2001:4860:4860::8888, but if I ping it, I also get a network unreachable.

Comment: You need to have global IPv6 addresses assigned if you want to use IPv6 on the public Internet. That is an entirely different question, so you should start a new question to ask about that.